# Display text in cell relative to matching cells in chosen area

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that is formatted like this:

[image: Image of text and numbers]

I am trying to generate a random number using RANDBETWEEN(1,5) and then show the text that is next to this number in my list (shown in picture).

What is the simplest way to show the text next to the number in the list as a formula of the cell with my random number?

Comment: Look into index/match or vlookup.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide any actual formula, I don't really understand the web pages.

Comment: Whoever voted to close for migration to SuperUser doesn't know that [tag:excel-formula] is on-topic for SO.  However, there is no attempt at trying any formulas first, which DOES make this off-topic for SO.  I've voted to close until an attempt is made at a formula.

Comment: Chrismas007 what do you mean? Have I done the question wrong?

Comment: @DrCharlieG Yes.  Stack Overflow is designed to help people writing code (or formulas in your case), who are stuck.  However, to get help, you first have to make an effort to write the formula yourself and show where you are stuck.  Additionally, it helps to show a screenshot of an example sheet (if you can't share the actual data then mask the data) for others to review.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Ok... I will try but I can't find anywhere, I will keep looking so if you must I guess take down my question

Comment: @DrCharlieG Scott Craner gave you formulas to look into. They are both relatively straight forward. Either try VLOOKUP or a combination of INDEX/MATCH. It's pretty straight forward if you look at how each of the functions work. Use the popup tips within excel to see what inputs it needs and search these functions on SO and youtube.

Comment: @DrCharlieG It takes 5 people to agree (we don't do any thing unilaterally here unless it is really bad and a moderator has to step in).  Right now you are at 3 votes to close (including mine).  If it does get closed, keep at it, and if you start to figure it out, re-ask your question with some of your work shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
E4=INDEX($B$6:$B$63,MATCH(E3,$A$6:$A$63,0))
```

or this

```
E4=VLOOKUP(E3,$A$6:$B$63,2,0)
```

Then copy to E5 and to the right.

Comment: ① You might want to use **0** as the *match_type* parameter of the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). There is no indication that this is sorted data let alone sorted in an ascending manner. ② Your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) needs a **table_array** parameter of **$A$6:$B$63** or **$A:$B** if you are going to retrieve the second column.

Comment: @kindoflost Thank you! That worked and thanks for being quick :D